# Unable to sign a file using gpg on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: encryption, ubuntu-18.04, public-key-encryption, gnupg

trying sign a file using gpg on Ubuntu 18.04 with following :

```
gpg --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4
libgcrypt 1.8.1
```

started the gpg-agent with following

```
gpg-agent --daemon --debug-level 9 --pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
```

exported the agent info by

```
export GPG_AGENT_INFO="~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent:$(pgrep gpg-agent):1"
```

and TTY info by

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
```

But when tried to sign a file using following command

```
gpg --output example.gpg --sign example.txt
```

The output is as follows

```
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> OK Pleased to meet you, process 25152
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- RESET
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> OK
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- OPTION ttyname=/dev/pts/2
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> OK
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- OPTION ttytype=xterm
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> OK
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- OPTION lc-ctype=C.UTF-8
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> OK
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- OPTION lc-messages=C.UTF-8
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> OK
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- GETINFO version
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> D 2.2.4
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> OK
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- OPTION allow-pinentry-notify
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> OK
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- OPTION agent-awareness=2.1.0
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> OK
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- SCD SERIALNO openpgp
gpg-agent[11793]: new connection to SCdaemon established (reusing)
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_10 -> SERIALNO openpgp
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_10 <- ERR 100696144 No such device <SCD>
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> ERR 100696144 No such device <SCD>
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- HAVEKEY 33F0F39FF1A5FA2A5F94CCD25F41F7F298CB2D2B 2E1C10D851E9F71B68923622C741DF42F2FE6AA2
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> OK
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- KEYINFO 33F0F39FF1A5FA2A5F94CCD25F41F7F298CB2D2B
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: agent_get_cache '33F0F39FF1A5FA2A5F94CCD25F41F7F298CB2D2B' (mode 2) ...
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: ... miss
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> S KEYINFO 33F0F39FF1A5FA2A5F94CCD25F41F7F298CB2D2B D - - - P - - -
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> OK
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- RESET
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> OK
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- SIGKEY 33F0F39FF1A5FA2A5F94CCD25F41F7F298CB2D2B
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> OK
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- SETKEYDESC Please+enter+the+passphrase+to+unlock+the+OpenPGP+secret+key:%0A%22Example+<Example@Example.com>%22%0A2048-bit+RSA+key,+ID+EF00F70672017CCC,%0Acreated+2017-11-06.%0A
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> OK
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- SETHASH 10 06F405A35FDACC3696FCF9ED5A1A221EF0881B63B9E1E4F7A63429940D64FC347D1BB756427CCB53B855DDF99D19C604B4292E7FE306246FC22ABB7F8690C399
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> OK
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- PKSIGN
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: agent_get_cache '33F0F39FF1A5FA2A5F94CCD25F41F7F298CB2D2B' (mode 2) ...
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: ... miss
gpg-agent[11793]: starting a new PIN Entry
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: connection to PIN entry established
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> INQUIRE PINENTRY_LAUNCHED 25154 curses 1.1.0 /dev/pts/2 xterm -
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- END
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: error calling pinentry: Permission denied <Pinentry>
gpg-agent[11793]: failed to unprotect the secret key: Permission denied
gpg-agent[11793]: failed to read the secret key
gpg-agent[11793]: command 'PKSIGN' failed: Permission denied <Pinentry>
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 -> ERR 83918849 Permission denied <Pinentry>
gpg: signing failed: Permission denied
gpg: signing failed: Permission denied
flectra@testforbld:~$ gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_9 <- [eof]
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_10 -> RESTART
gpg-agent[11793]: DBG: chan_10 <- OK
```